# Proper pattern to encapsulate log setup in golang

Tags: go, deferred-execution

When trying to move log setup code into a separate function I ran into inability to hide the destination file object from the `main` function. In the following **INCORRECT** simplified example the attempt is made to setup log writing to both Stderr and a file via a single function call:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func SetupLogging() {
    logFile, err := os.OpenFile("test.log", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    defer logFile.Close()

    log.SetOutput(io.MultiWriter(os.Stderr, logFile))
}

func main() {
    SetupLogging()
    log.Println("Test message")
}
```

Clearly is does not work because `defer` closes the log file at the end of the `SetupLogging` function.

A working example below adds extra code and IMHO looses some clarity if repeated in a larger application as a pattern:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func SetupLogging() *os.File {
    logFile, err := os.OpenFile("test.log", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }

    log.SetOutput(io.MultiWriter(os.Stderr, logFile))
    return logFile
}

func main() {
    logf := SetupLogging()
    defer logf.Close()

    log.Println("Test message")
}
```

Is there a different way to fully encapsulate open file management into a function, yet still nicely release the handle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have now successfully used the below approach for about a year in multiple projects. The idea is to return a function from the setup call. That resulting function contains the destruction logic. Here is an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func LogSetupAndDestruct() func() {
    logFile, err := os.OpenFile("test.log", os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_RDWR, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }

    log.SetOutput(io.MultiWriter(os.Stderr, logFile))

    return func() {
        e := logFile.Close()
        if e != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Problem closing the log file: %s\n", e)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    defer LogSetupAndDestruct()()

    log.Println("Test message")
}
```

It is using a closure around the cleanup logic being deferred.

A somewhat more elaborate public example of using this approach is in the Viper code: [here is the return from a test initializer](https://github.com/spf13/viper/blob/9fca10189b1307bba68b2cd487dd93da0bfbda06/viper_test.go#L167-L170), and [here it is used to encapsulate the cleanup logic and objects](https://github.com/spf13/viper/blob/9fca10189b1307bba68b2cd487dd93da0bfbda06/viper_test.go#L607-L608)

Answer (score 1):

The proper way of doing this is passing the handle in main to `SetupLogging`:

```
func SetupLogging(lf *os.File) {
    log.SetOutput(io.MultiWriter(os.Stderr, logFile))
    log.Println("Started")
}

func main() {
    logFile, err := os.OpenFile("test.log", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    defer logFile.Close()
    SetupLogging(logFile)
    log.Println("Test message")
}
```

Another option is to use [`runtime.SetFinalizer`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#SetFinalizer), but it's not always guaranteed to run before main exits.

```
func SetupLogging() {
    logFile, err := os.OpenFile("test.log", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    runtime.SetFinalizer(logFile, func(h *os.File) {
        h.Close()
    })

    log.SetOutput(io.MultiWriter(os.Stderr, logFile))
}
```

Comment: The first example does not serve the purpose which is exactly to lighten the boilerplate code in an outer function (the example does not encapsulate the behavior into a function). As you and documentation mention the second example does not guarantee the desired behaviour (I think it is even unlikely at a program end). So it is a no-go either. Do I understand that your answer is essentially "There is no way to do that in Go"? (which is fine, just need to know).

Comment: @VladDidenko Yes, there's no way to do that in Go. Returning the `os.File` and using `defer f.Close()` in main is the only proper way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using channels, here is my approach

```
type InfoLog struct {
    InfoChan chan string
    CloseChan chan struct{} //empty signal
    log *log.Logger
    file *os.File
}

func NewInfoLog(file *os.File) *InfoLog {
    return &InfoLog{
        InfoChan: make(chan string),
        CloseChan: make(chan struct{}),
        log: log.New(file, "TAG", log.Ldate|log.Ltime),
        file: file,
    }
}

func (i *InfoLog) listen() {
    for {
        select {
        case infoMsg := <-i.InfoChan:
            i.log.Println(infoMsg)
        case <-i.CloseChan:
            i.file.Close()
            close(i.InfoChan)
        }
    }
}
```

then in main

```
func main() {
    infoLog := NewInfoLog(ANY_OPEN_FILE_HERE)
    go infoLog.listen()
    infoLog.InfoChan <- "msg"
    infoLog.InfoChan <- "msg"
    infoLog.InfoChan <- "msg"
    infoLog.CloseChan <- struct{}{}
    // exits normaly
}
```

you can see an asynchronous log system i have made for a complete example: https://github.com/sescobb27/ciudad-gourmet/blob/master/services/log_service.go

Comment: I was curious if this can be done with the standard logger, so that existing code does not have to care about new patterns. I ended up with something similar to InfoLog, also using channels.

Answer (score 0):

in case where multiple "teardown" processes are needed, great solution to this is using google context package (https://blog.golang.org/context). advantage is that you can teardown all currently executing procedures with single context. smth like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/net/context"
)

func LogSetup(ctx context.Context) error {
    logFile, err := os.OpenFile("test.log", os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_RDWR, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    log.SetOutput(io.MultiWriter(os.Stderr, logFile))
    // here we could f.ex. execute:
    // sendLogOutputToExternalService(ctx)
    // and it could have it's own teardown procedure
    // which would be called on main context's expiration
    go func() {
       for _ = range ctx.Done() {
         err := logFile.Close()
         if err = nil {
             fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Problem closing the log file: %s\n", e)
        }
    }()
    return nil
}


func main() {
    var stopAll func()
    mainContext, stopAll = context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer stopAll()

    err := LogSetup(mainContext)
    if err!=nil {
        log.Fatal("error while initializing logging") 
    }

    log.Println("Test message")
}
```